# Web scraping - filtering results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

So I'm new to python and very new to web scraping and could use some help. Even though I really understand the language, I have managed to scrape (ignore the pun) something together. I am trying to scrape prices from certain steam market items and this is what I have so far:

```
import urllib.request
import re

urls = ["http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29"]
i=0
pattern = re.compile(b'<span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">\s+(.+?)\s+</span>')

while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    titles = re.findall (pattern,htmltext)

    print (titles)
    i+=1
```

This gives a result like this:

```
[b'471,50 p&#1091;&#1073;.', b'CDN&#36; 9.50', b'Rp 103 500.99', b'&#36;8.39 USD', b'&#36;8.40 USD', b'499,99 p&#1091;&#1073;.', b'499,99 p&#1091;&#1073;.', b'6,90&#8364;', b'6,90&#8364;', b'6,90&#8364;']
```

As you can see, this isn't very friendly to the eye at all, what I want to get is just the price (only USD) from the cheapest item only (In this case: `b'&#36;8.39 USD'`). How can I filter the results so it only gives me the lowest price from the list like this: `8.39 USD`.

As I said before, I am very much new to python and web scraping, so may need a little more help with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use an *HTML parser*, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

The idea is to iterate over results (`div` with id `searchResultsRows`) and get all `span` elements with class `market_listing_price`. Then, for each `span` extract the price using regular expressions:

```
import re
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29"]

pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9\.,]+)')
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))

    prices = []
    for price in soup.select('div#searchResultsRows span.market_listing_price'):
        match = pattern.search(price.text)
        if match:
            prices.append(float(match.group(1).replace(',', '.')))

    print(prices)
```

Prints:

```
[6.26, 5.45, 458.0, 398.27, 57.5, 50.0, 8.0, 6.97, 8.12, 7.07, 6.8, 5.92, 499.99, 434.79, 6.87, 5.99, 502.97, 437.38, 6.9, 6.0]
```

As a side note, you may have noticed that there is no single currency set, each price goes in it's own one - this is what you need to take into account also.